# Android NFC read Tag only on button click

Tags: android, button, nfc

I am slowly learning Android. Currently I am on NFC, I have studied a couple of tutorials and I start understanding a bit better how it works and how to read and write tags, what I can do now on the ones I bought.
Most people want their app to start as soon as they are close to a tag but for learning purposes I would like to start the discovery only when I hit a button, in other words, I want to control the discovery. 
I understand that in order to have the app starting immediately, we implement the filter  ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED in the Manifest.xml
I also read that filtering with intents works only if our app is not in foreground. If our app is running in the foreground, it won't be notified, so we have to use NFC Foreground dispatch.

What I can't figure out is how I can manipulate the filter and the foreground in order they only react to my click of a button.

My other question is : Is it going to work for both Read and Write buttons?

Could somebody please help? If you give me some code, please be so kind to explain it, I am really after learning and understanding :-)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library called NDEF tools - [link](https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/).

I used it some time ago, to read and write NFC tag on button click. Take a look at the library and my code and play around with it.

```
public class NFCReadActivity extends NfcReaderActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_nfc);

        // Read the tag, without prompting how/who should read it
        setDetecting(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void readNdefMessage(Message message)
    {
        if (message != null)
        {
            // Iterate through all records in message
            for (int k = 0; k < message.size(); k++)
            {
                Record record = message.get(k);

                // Get record type (record.getClass().getSimpleName())
                if (record instanceof TextRecord)
                {
                    // Get NFC message
                    String message = ((TextRecord) record).getText();

                    // Inform user
                    Crouton.makeText(this, message, Style.CONFIRM).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // An empty NDEF message was read
    @Override
    protected void readEmptyNdefMessage()
    {
        Crouton.makeText(this, getString(R.string.NFC_empty_message), Style.ALERT).show();
    }

    // Something was read via NFC, but it was not an NDEF message
    @Override
    protected void readNonNdefMessage()
    {
        Crouton.makeText(this, getString(R.string.NFC_non_ndef_message), Style.ALERT).show();
    }

    // NFC feature was found and is currently enabled
    @Override
    protected void onNfcStateEnabled()
    {

    }

    // NFC feature was found but is currently disabled
    @Override
    protected void onNfcStateDisabled()
    {
        Crouton.makeText(this, getString(R.string.NFC_state_disabled), Style.ALERT).show();
        new GoToSettingsDialog(this).showNFCSettings();
    }

    // NFC setting changed since last check. For example, the user enabled NFC in the wireless settings
    @Override
    protected void onNfcStateChange(boolean enabled)
    {

    }

    // This device does not have NFC hardware
    @Override
    protected void onNfcFeatureNotFound()
    {
        Crouton.makeText(this, getString(R.string.NFC_not_found), Style.ALERT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marko, I was aware of the NDEF tools already. I think I understand most of your code, but what I don't get is the 3 lines of code starting with :
// Read the tag, without prompting how/who should read it.
What is it exactly you are doing ?

Comment: Method **setDetecting()** comes from the NDEF library, it does what it says, it starts listening/detecting for any NFC tags. The idea is  that when the user clicks the button, you open a new activity, that can read NFC tags, and when you leave the activity, it stops. You could also implement it without opening new acitivty.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. If in my read button I call the setDetecting(), it will come up with"I see a tag", then I can do what's necessary to read it, right? Does it mean that for my write button, I need to call the same method again to detect the tag and then do what's necessary to write on it? 
The readNdefMessage() is the method to call in order to read the tag, right? Do I put that in my myButton1.setOnClickListener() method?

Comment: Noupe. For now start slowly, firstly when you click your button, you should open a new activity, with the code I provided (NFCReadActivity). Than you don't have to do anything, just put the NFC to the back of the phone, and method **readNdefMessage** will be called by itself, if it can read the NFC tag. For writing to NFC tag, there is another file, that extends NfcTagWriterActivity, can provide the code if needed.

Comment: Sure, if you will have any problems, just ask.. :)

Comment: I am missing something, I have been studying the Android doc and I make a mistake when I transfer everything to the 2nd activity. Lets say I have my main activity with 1 button, nothing else and when I click on it I go to the activity 2 in which the tag is going to be read. Where do I declare my NFC adapter for example, in activity 1 or 2? I have created my button and a method related to it and and intent, like this :

public void OpenAndRead(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReadTagActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
but I never go to activity 2. Why ?

Comment: I JUST DID IT ! Thank you for your kind help !

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that! You are more than welcome :)